# Do Ribbon based MFC applications work on Windows pre-Vista/7?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, ribbon

Can MFC applications with Ribbon toolbars built under VS2010 be run on versions of Windows that were released before the ribbon was designed - e.g. XP or W2K, not just Vista or W7?

If no, what (if anything) can be done to make them work?

Comment: Well for a start the .dll's won't be installed by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will run on XP with SP3.
But not for older systems, as applications compiled with VS2010 require at least XP SP3 to run (requirement of the C-Runtime library).

Answer (score 1):

According to ["Encountered an improper argument" running a Windows XP MFC Ribbon Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514535/encountered-an-improper-argument-running-a-windows-xp-mfc-ribbon-application) it should work. The question also says, that MFC libraries are statically linked to work on XP (I don't know why the dynamic versions shouldn't work ...)

I'd guess there might be some differences in the appearance, but I suggest to try it out to see if you can live with it.